# MAGENTO2 : HOW TO RECTIFY WHICH PROMOTION IS APPLIED ON THE RESPECTIVE ITEM IN AN ORDER

Tags: magento2, promotions

I have an order with an Item having some special price on it. I want to know whether if it's Product's special price, tier price or any catalog rule promotion price. Reason for asking this question is I send this data to some third party to generate the report on basis of promotions(special price, tier price or catalog rule special price). I want to achieve it by writing a code in magento2. Can anyone help out in this?

Comment: You can check in the quote and quote item table, there you will find applied_coupon field values. HOpe this will help you.

Comment: Thanks @Nits for the quick reply . I can easily get the cart rule discount from the quote tables. I want the discounts on the basis of product special price, tier price or catalog rule discounts.

Comment: I've been looking into this as well and largely come up short. I found this though - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19858